# Reference request: Cohomology of Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Is it true that the group
$$H^1(Gal(K^{ab}/K)/\mu_{\nu}(Gal(K_{\nu}^{ab}/K_{\nu})),E_{p^n})$$
is always p-divisible? Or are there any conditions which, when satisfied, guarantee its p-divisibility?
Here, $()^{ab}$ denotes the maximal Abelian extension of a field, $K_{\nu}$ is the localization of a field $K$ at a finite prime $\nu$, $\mu_{\nu}:Gal(K_{\nu}^{ab}/K_{\nu})\rightarrow Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ is induced by the injection $K\rightarrow K_{\nu}$ and $E_{p^n}$ are the $p^n$-torsion points of a (non-singular) elliptic curve $E$, defined over $K$.

I am not an expert on the subject, so please have mercy on my soul.

Comment: A couple questions. I assume you don't want torsion points defined over K--you don't want a trivial action, yeah? So what do you mean? Do you want E[p^n](K^ab)? Also, have you tried the obvious like of attack using inflation-restriction sequence? Also, have you tried the only tenable case (eg. K=Q)? Finally, where did this question come from?